# Fitting rectangle among 4 spheres

Tags: 3d, gps, geometry, intersection

I was wondering does anyone have an idea how to solve to following task:

[image]

4 poles are given in the space each with different height. Their base is a convex quad. From each pole there is a rope connected to an object. The coordinates in 3D for all the poles are defined. Knowing the position of the object makes it straight forward to find the rope lengths. The task is solving the reverse problem - knowing the lengths of the 4 ropes to find its position in 3D space.

There are two versions - the easy and the hard one. The easy one is when the 4 ropes are connected to a single point - the problem can be solved by finding the intersection of 4 spheres with their centers at the top of the poles and radii the 4 lengths of the ropes. I do it similarly to how GPS works - intersection of the 2 spheres is a circle. The intersection of that circle with the 3rd sphere gives me 2 points in result. I use the 4th sphere as a control one to find which of the two lies inside the working space.

The hard one is when the poles are connected each to a different point which form another quad. I given up trying to solve it for a general quad so I tried to do it for a rectangle with sizes (d1, d2) which plane should be always parallel to the floor(blue region below - XZ plane) which sides are parallel to X and Z axes. This simplifies the task a lot. Knowing the position(center) of the rectangle makes it again straight forward finding the lengths of the 4 ropes. However I want to find position of the rectangle knowing the lengths A, B, C, D of the 4 ropes.

[image]

What I did was using the 3 spheres to find the position of one of rectangle's and the 4th one as a control one. The centers of the 3 spheres line in a plane so I change the coordinate system in such a way that the center of the 1st(A) one is the origin O(0,0,0). The 2nd one(B) is on the X axis at distance d. The 3rd one(D) is at coordinates (p,q,0). The lower left point of the rectangle lies on the 1st sphere and has coordinates:

```
  A(x,y,z)           on 1st sphere      R1^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2

  B(x+d1,y,z)        on 2nd sphere      R2^2 = (x+d1-d)^2 + y^2 + z^2

  C(x,y1+d,z)        on 3rd sphere      R3^2 = (x-p)^2 + (y+d1-q)^2 + z^2
```

Lower right B of the rectangle lies on the 2nd sphere d1 units on the right from A and C d2 units up on the 3rd sphere.

Here I have 3 unknowns (x,y,z) and 3 quadratic equations which are quite easy to solve by substitutions and I find

```
The X coordinate x = 0.5 * (R2^2 - R1^2 - (d1 - d)^2) / (d1 - d)

The Y coordinate y = 0.5 * (R4^2 - R1^2 - (d2 - q)^2 - p^2 + 2*p*x) / (d2 - q)

For the Z coordinate z1 = sqrt(R1^2 - x^2 - y^2) and z2 = -sqrt(R1^2 - x^2 - y^2)
```

Using the 4th sphere as a control eliminates z1 or z2. Changing back to the original coordinates system we can find the actual center of the rectangle.

This however turns out to work only when the poles are with equal heights. Changing them to different gives wrong results. Which means either there is error in the calculation or some wrong assumptions is made. I can not figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Well you've assumed the poles are the same height. If you can't assume that, then you'll have to assume the rope intersects the plane of your rectangle at the same angle, or you'll need one other variable as well as rope length for each corner.

Comment: I was suspecting that is one of the reasons if not a mistake during calculations but I can't figure it out where I had made such unintentional assumption? But what I am using is just general sphere equations. There is always a solution and the check is very simple - I pick a point in the space, center the rectangle there and calculate the lengths A,B,C,D to each of the poles. Then I give these lengths to the solver to return me a point and it must match the initial one.

Comment: Calculate the lengths to the poles means you know the height of them, or the angle the rope intersects the plane otherwise you couldn't do it. No way you can reverse it with just the lengths, how many different pole heights could satisfy a rope length of A?

Comment: Well obviously they intersect the plane at different angles in general. I know not just the heights of the poles but their 3D positions actually. The other parameters I know is that the plane is parallel to the ground, size of the rectangle and that its sides are parallel to the world axes(and that the first 2 poles are actually on the X axis). I think it should be enough even with different heights for the poles?

Comment: Exactly you know the height and the base (from the coordinate of the base of the pole therefore you know the hypotenuse with some simple trig. If you didn't know the height or the base, you'd be equally flummoxed in terms of calculating the rope length would you not?

Comment: Which hypotenuse exactly?